# Can the values of HTTP Origin and Referer values be set from SOAP UI or any such tool?

Tags: wcf, http, rest, header

I have a WCF REST service which I intend to respond only to requests from a certain domain. I planned to check the HTTP Origin and Referer headers to validate if the request is coming from the domain I am expecting. But as I was trying the SOAP UI tool, I noticed that we can add any value to the Headers and make the request! Is there a way to prevent the header values from being modified using such tools or addons?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to just respond to a specific sender, you need to validate your sender by using IP address filtering in conjunction with digital signature or client certificate to be sure your are receiving data from the source you expected not from impersonate middle node in network.

I guess there is no other option for you.

Answer (score 0):

in SoapUI, You can add the referer with your value, in the headers of your request